# Add a {0} variable to an Excel spreadsheet name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm working on creating Excel spreadsheets displaying the data currently showing on my page for my intranet. It's working smoothly, but I wish to have different file names (depending on the user logged in, the time of creation etc.).

Here is where the name of the Excel file is determined :

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Activity.xls");
```

As you can see, everytime I'll press the Excel button, it'll reach its controller that will take care of retrieving the data / saving / creating an `.xls` file named `Activity`.

I'm new to the technology, and heard of adding parameters to strings in C# using `{0}`. **Would there be something similar so that I can name my files like such :**

```
Activity_UserName_DateOfCreation
```

Here is the Excel part of my controller, not the data collection :

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Excel(string user)
{
    var products = new System.Data.DataTable("Activity"); // Creates the DataTable
    products.Columns.Add("Project", typeof(string)); // Adds a column
    IEnumerable<Project> lp = _service.List(strUser, strYear, strMonth); // Creates a list of the projects
    UserActivityDb db = new UserActivityDb(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    lp = lp.Where(p => (true == db.ExistUserActivity(int.Parse(strYear), int.Parse(strMonth), ListDaysOfMonth, p.ProjectId, strUser)));

    List<string[]> lstInts = new List<string[]>();

    foreach (Project p in lp)
    {
        string strInts = db.getFormattedData(int.Parse(strYear), int.Parse(strMonth), ListDaysOfMonth, p.ProjectId, strUser, null, 0);
        string[] ints = strInts.Split(';');

        lstInts.Add(ints);              
        products.Rows.Add(p.Name, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // Adds an empty row to be filed with the correct values later

    }

    int i = 0;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 0;
    foreach (string[] tab in lstInts) // Adds the activity data cell by cell
    {
        while (tab[z] != "")
        {
            products.Rows[i][y] = tab[z];
            y++;
            z++;
        }            
        i++;
        y = 1;
        z = 0;

    }                  

    var grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = products;
    grid.DataBind();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Activity.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return View("Excel");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just do something like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=Activity_{0}_{1}.xls",strUser, DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MMddyyyy")));
```

Comment: I have tried it, it gives me in error since `Response.AddHeader` has a limited amount of parameters.

Comment: Did you try that with the `string.Format()` around your file name? That call above only has 2 parameters in the `Response.AddHeader` call.

Comment: @ChristopherK. welcome! Would you please accept this as the answer for your question? And, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna add an alternative to DrewJordans approach here, even though that works without any issues whatsoever. Just like this approach better, for readability:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=Activity_{strUser}_{DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MMddyyyy")}.xls");
```

Just adding [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) if you wanna read more about interpolated strings.

Comment: yeah, I gotta get started with the 6.0 features, I do like that better.